# paper_trail show log of changes to a member (no method for each error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

I'm trying to show a log for changes on a particular member in the show view. The members information is there and the version history is working.

I'm having troubles showing versions/changes log for that particular member. I get this error:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for #<PaperTrail::Version:0x007f55f23ee348>):
```

I have this in my controller:

```
    # Detailed Member Profile
    def show
        @versions = PaperTrail::Version.find(params[:id])
        @members_main = Members::Main.find(params[:id])
    end
```

And this in my show view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <% @versions.each do |version| %>
            <li>
                <%= l(version.created_at, format: "%-d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S %Z") %><br/>
                Event ID: <%= version.id %><br/>
                <b>Target:</b> <%= version.item_type %>
                <small>(id: <%= version.item_id %>)</small>; <b>action</b> <%= version.event %>;<br/>
                <div>
                    More info:
                    <pre><%= version.object %></pre>
                </div>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Model:

```
class Members::Main < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Add Paper Trail
    has_paper_trail

end
```

Comment: It would be good to post the whole exception you get.

Comment: I edited the question and put the full error in.

Comment: I think if you modify it slightly then it should work as you wish. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `find` method of the ActiveRecord returns only one object. And that object does not have an `each` method.

See the documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find).

In particular this line `@versions = PaperTrail::Version.find(params[:id])`. It returns an object for the given *id*. But that object does not have a method called `each`. That is your error text.

What you probably expected was that it returns an array, but it obviously did not.

Try to change it to `@versions = PaperTrail::Version.find([params[:id]])` and I believe it should work. Note the *brackets*.

Comment: Or `PaperTrail::Version.where(id: params[:id])` which may be more familiar if you speak SQL.

Comment: Thanks this helped me on another problem.